# Ajax, pass variable array of parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, razor-pages

I'm trying to make a general function to call partial views. They won't all have the same numbers and types of parameters

I can't find how to send it properly to the controller

So a page will build a array like this

```
 $('#btn_New').on('click', function () {
                var params = {};
                params.index =count;
                
                CallAddPartial(params, "?handler=NewPeriodPartial", "tbl_Periods");
                count++;
            });
```

General function is like this, it receives the array fine but the controller gets 0 for index

```
function CallAddPartial(paramsArray, handler, tbl) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: handler,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(paramsArray),
        success: function (response) {
            $('#' + tbl +' tr:last').after(response);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

```
 public PartialViewResult OnGetNewPeriodPartial(int index)
        {
            return Partial("NewPeriod", new Periods.NewPeriodModel(_context, index));
        }
```

I'm expecting int index to have a value (count value)

I have tried with and without stringify, to receive a string as well

Comment: Could you share your full html code so that we can reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it:

```
<form method="get"><button  id="btn_New"> submit</button></form>  

@section Scripts
{<script>
        $('#btn_New').on('click', function () {
            var params = {};
            params.index = 1;             
        CallAddPartial(params, "?handler=NewPeriodPartial", "tbl_Periods");
            count++;
        }); 
        function CallAddPartial(paramsArray, handler, tbl) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: handler,
                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: paramsArray,  //change here...
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#' + tbl + ' tr:last').after(response);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        }</script>
}
```

result:

[image]